# Symfony2: routing with controller as a service not working

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to use controllers as a service in my Symfony 2.7 project.

This was my previous routing.yml before i tried the services:

```
affiliate_api_get_adblock:
    path:     /api/1.0/admin/affiliate/adblock
    defaults: { _controller: AffiliateBundle:AffiliateApi:adblock }
```

It works perfectly. It routes the path to the AffiliateApiController in the AffiliateBundle and executes the adblockAction-Method.

Then i created the following service:

```
services:
    company.affiliate_api_controller:
        class: CompanyName\AffiliateBundle\Controller\AffiliateApiController
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

When I want to instantiate the controller per DI-Container, it works: `$c = $this->get('company.affiliate_api_controller');`

But when i then try to use the service name in the routing.yml instead of the class name as described in the Symfony docs, errors where thrown:

```
affiliate_api_get_adblock:
    path:     /api/1.0/admin/affiliate/adblock
    defaults: { _controller: company.affiliate_api_controller:adblock }
```

What happens then requesting this route, is a 500 error with the following message:

> Controller "company.affiliate_api_controller:adblock" for URI
>   "/api/1.0/admin/affiliate/adblock" is not callable. 500 Internal
>   Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to declare the `defaults` in your `routing.yml` with the suffix `Action`:

```
affiliate_api_get_adblock:
    path:     /api/1.0/admin/affiliate/adblock
    defaults: { _controller: company.affiliate_api_controller:adblockAction }
```